# how to update whole database without losing data

Tags: php, mysql

I am using mysql database for my site.
I have create one site using codeigniter php framework and mysql.

Now after few months I have updated that site and also the database.
I have added some new columns to my database table not deleted or alert any previous one.

Now I want to update my site but don't want to lose data that I already have right now.

Is there anyway I can update database without losing the data present in it.

Comment: take a backup of DB and then apply alter update !!

Comment: What do you mean by "alert any previous one"?

Comment: @Mischa probably altered

Answer (score 0):

[SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/) has a great feature called "Schema Synchronization tool" which will do it

they also have a blog comparing other methods of doing it

http://blog.webyog.com/2012/10/16/so-how-do-you-sync-your-database-schema/

Im sure other similar tools can do it also

Edit:

[Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) also has this feature

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html

Answer (score 0):

If your database is created/updated automatically by some modeling tool, I think the best you way you should do is to understand those changes and write the "alter table" statements yourself and run it in your deployment.

As user1281385 pointed in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22012478/1033539 , there may be some tool that can help you generate those statements.